# HttpClient not working in Xamarin / Android App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create one sample application in Xamarin / Android, Which downloads one image from Internet and displays it in ImageView. But soon after executing `var imageContent = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (ImageUrl);` The UI / Application hangs. No call back response is coming. I am adding my full source code for you reference. Please help whats wrong in my sample.

```
[Activity (Label = "ImageDownloadSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private const string ImageUrl = "http://www.olympusimage.com.sg/content/000006422.jpg";
    private ImageView imgView;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        var button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.downloadImage);
        imgView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        button.Click+=((sender, e) => 
             DownloadImageAsync());

    }

    private async void DownloadImageAsync()
    {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
            imgView.SetImageResource (Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuGallery);

            var imageContent = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (ImageUrl);
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string localFilename = "mytestImage.jpg";
            string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);
            File.WriteAllBytes (localPath, imageContent); 


            var localImage = new Java.IO.File (localFilename);
            if (localImage.Exists ()) {

                var bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (localImage.AbsolutePath);
                imgView.SetImageBitmap (bitmapImage);


        }

    }
}
```

}

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

They have a sample app that does exactly this:  https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/AsyncImageAndroid/AsyncImageAndroid/MainActivity.cs

Also, that image you're trying to download looks pretty huge...I'd definitely get something more reasonable just to rule that out as an error while trying to get things working.

Comment: That sample is implemented with WebClient. I was trying with latest HttpClient. Why i need to stick with old method...??

Comment: You probably don't.  Can you update the question to say exactly what line your app is hanging on?  Is there anything written to the console?

Comment: You should also use a smaller image.  I don't think you should be loading an 8MB image into a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Check the exception! If you have timeout set HttpClient.Timeout larger!

Answer (score -1):

You might need to set up the event handler as such:

```
button.Click+=(async (sender, e) => DownloadImageAsync());
```

To indicate that it contains code that can run asynchronously